# npm run production after upgrade to laravel-mix 4.0.16 doesn't work

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-mix

- Laravel version 5.5
- Laravel Mix Version 4.0.16
- Node Version v10.16.0
- NPM Version 6.9.0
- OS Centos 7

**Description**

After I upgrade laravel-mix from 1* to 4.0.16 by using `npm update` command, `npm run production` doesn't work but `npm run watch` command works correctly.

**package.json**

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.19.0",
        "bootstrap-sass": "^3.4.1",
        "cross-env": "^5.0.1",
        "jquery": "^3.4.1",
        "laravel-mix": "^4.0.16",
        "lodash": "^4.17.4",
        "vue": "^2.6.10"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "vue-js-modal": "^1.3.31",
        "vue-router": "^3.0.6",
        "vue-slider-component": "^3.0.32",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
    }
}
```

**npm run production error**

```
[jezygroup@server jezyGroup]$ npm run production

> @ production /home/jezygroup/jezyGroup
> cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

 10% building 0/1 modules 1 active ...p/resources/assets/js/AdminPanel/app.j 10% building 1/1 modules 0 activenpm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ production: `cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ production script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/jezygroup/.npm/_logs/2019-06-06T11_39_30_311Z-debug.log
```

**log file**

```
[jezygroup@server jezyGroup]$ cat /home/jezygroup/.npm/_logs/2019-06-06T11_39_30_311Z-debug.log
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/home/jezygroup/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.0/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/home/jezygroup/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.0/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'production' ]
2 info using npm@6.9.0
3 info using node@v10.16.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'preproduction', 'production', 'postproduction' ]
5 info lifecycle @~preproduction: @
6 info lifecycle @~production: @
7 verbose lifecycle @~production: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle @~production: PATH: /home/jezygroup/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/home/jezygroup/jezyGroup/node_modules/.bin:/home/jezygroup/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.0/bin:/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib/path-bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/opt/cpanel/composer/bin:/home/jezygroup/.local/bin:/home/jezygroup/bin
9 verbose lifecycle @~production: CWD: /home/jezygroup/jezyGroup
10 silly lifecycle @~production: Args: [ '-c',
10 silly lifecycle   'cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js' ]
11 silly lifecycle @~production: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle @~production: Failed to exec production script
13 verbose stack Error: @ production: `cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/home/jezygroup/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:198:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/jezygroup/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
14 verbose pkgid @
15 verbose cwd /home/jezygroup/jezyGroup
16 verbose Linux 3.10.0-962.3.2.lve1.5.24.7.el7.x86_64
17 verbose argv "/home/jezygroup/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.0/bin/node" "/home/jezygroup/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.0/bin/npm" "run" "production"
18 verbose node v10.16.0
19 verbose npm  v6.9.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error @ production: `cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the @ production script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

**webpack.mix.js**

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');
// panel assets
mix.scripts([
    'resources/assets/vendor/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js',
    'resources/assets/vendor/admin-panel/js/bootstrap.min.js',
    'resources/assets/vendor/admin-panel/js/material.min.js',
    'resources/assets/vendor/admin-panel/js/perfect-scrollbar.jquery.min.js',
    'resources/assets/vendor/admin-panel/js/arrive.min.js',
    'resources/assets/vendor/admin-panel/js/jquery.validate.min.js',
    'resources/assets/vendor/admin-panel/js/bootstrap-notify.js',
    'resources/assets/vendor/admin-panel/js/jquery.select-bootstrap.js',
    'resources/assets/vendor/admin-panel/js/material-dashboard.js',
], 'public/js/AdminPanel.js');

mix.js('resources/assets/js/AdminPanel/app.js', 'public/js/app.js').version();

mix.styles([
    'resources/assets/vendor/admin-panel/css/bootstrap.min.css',
    'resources/assets/vendor/admin-panel/css//bootstrap-rtl.min.css',
    'resources/assets/vendor/admin-panel/css/material-dashboard.css',
    'resources/assets/vendor/admin-panel/css/mokas.css',
    'resources/assets/vendor/admin-panel/css/custom.css',
], 'public/css/AdminPanel.css');

//================================================================
//=========================FRONTEND MIX ==========================
//================================================================


//===Main
mix.styles([
    'resources/assets/vendor/frontend/css/bootstrap-rtl.css',
    'resources/assets/vendor/frontend/css/elegant-icons.css',
    'resources/assets/vendor/frontend/css/animate.css',
    'resources/assets/vendor/frontend/css/slick.css',
    'resources/assets/vendor/frontend/css/magnific-popup.css',
    'resources/assets/vendor/frontend/css/fontiran.css',
    'resources/assets/vendor/frontend/css/FontAwesome.min.css',
    'resources/assets/vendor/frontend/css/toastr.min.css',
    'resources/assets/vendor/frontend/css/style.css',
    'resources/assets/vendor/frontend/css/responsive.css',
],'public/css/front.min.css');

mix.scripts([
    'resources/assets/vendor/frontend/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js',
    'resources/assets/vendor/frontend/js/bootstrap.min.js',
    'resources/assets/vendor/frontend/js/jquery.easing.js',
    'resources/assets/vendor/frontend/js/wow.min.js',
    'resources/assets/vendor/frontend/js/toastr.min.js',
    'resources/assets/vendor/frontend/js/magnific-popup.min.js',
    'resources/assets/vendor/frontend/js/jquery.scrollUp.min.js',
    'resources/assets/vendor/frontend/js/slick.min.js',
    'resources/assets/vendor/frontend/js/main.js',
],'public/js/front.min.js').version();
// Request wizard
mix.js('resources/assets/js/RequestWizard/app.js', 'public/js/wizard-request.min.js').version();
```

Comment: The problem may be in the webpack.mix.js configuration.
Can you copy here the content of this file?

Comment: added webpack.mix.js file

Answer (score 0):

Update your package.json with the [latest](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/package.json), specifically the "scripts" part.

```js
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.19",
        "bootstrap": "^4.1.0",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "jquery": "^3.4.1",
        "laravel-mix": "^4.0.16",
        "lodash": "^4.17.5",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
        "sass": "^1.15.2",
        "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
        "vue": "^2.6.10",
        "vue-js-modal": "^1.3.31",
        "vue-router": "^3.0.6",
        "vue-slider-component": "^3.0.32",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
    }
}
```